# What coordinate system is this with North and East?

Tags: coordinate-system, finland

What coordinate system is this? With label 'North' and 'East'.
All the data point lies in Southern Finland.
I tried UTM and http://projfinder.com/. Couldn't figure out...

[image]

Comment: What is the data supposed to represent? Trees? Villages? Lakes? Archeological finds?

Comment: The data points represent disease deaths in Finland. Each point is one death case.

Comment: Are the northings and eastings truncated? The columns look skinny. Can you post that in text format instead of a png?

Comment: Where did you get this data? Please post a link.

Comment: I don't think so. They are the way they look like in the picture I posted. No more numbers than that. When I read them in FME, the relative location looks correct, but I'd like to compile them with other data point with known coordinate system

Comment: The data are private for research purpose, so unfortunate I can't share it publicly.

Comment: Then get back to whoever gave you the data and ask them?

Comment: Can it be a local system created by surveyors for specific area?

Comment: It is not right timing to ask the person who I received data from, so I'd like to figure it out as much as I could...

Comment: @Daniel_P_GEO
It's possible. These are really old data. If it is the case, is there a way to convert them into another coordinate system?

Comment: If you can find/learn the origin of the coordinates, you may convert them into another coordinate system.

Comment: @Sassa If there is no known projection then automatically no. Depends on the amount of points, you can create a vector layer in another CRS and digitize the points by yourself. Ofc it works only with limited number of points.

Comment: @Daniel_P_GEO Oh no, there are more than 9000 points!  :, (

Comment: Possibly you will find the answer here: http://www.kolumbus.fi/eino.uikkanen/geodocsgb/ficoords.htm `Finnish Geodetic Institute has created an online conversion service for coordinate conversions between all coordinate reference systems used nationally in Finland. This service is embedded in the` ["Paikkatietoikkuna" map service](https://kartta.paikkatietoikkuna.fi/?lang=en).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136220/discussion-on-question-by-sassa-what-coordinate-system-is-this-with-north-and-ea).

Comment: I guess the data are in EPSG code series 2391-2394. The first coordinate of Easting defines the KKJ zone number - 1xxxxxx ->Zone 1 -> EPSG:2391. Both N and E coordinates should have 7 numbers for full meters. Widen the coordinate fields in Excel. The green corner in the cells may mean that numbers are stored as text. Hover on top of a cell and you should see some message.

Answer (score 1):

I think they may be in EPSG::3067, ETRS89 / TM35FIN(E,N), with truncated values. The first coordinate pair (in E,N) may actually be 420000, 7190000.

The GKFINxx zones don't cover enough zones to match with either the easting or the northing data (in case the columns were labeled incorrectly) so I don't think it can be one of those.

As user30184 suggested, they also could be in KKJ zone 3 / Unified coordinate system (EPSG::2393).

Comment: Thank you! It IS truncated numbers and now I can have them on my GIS map properly! : )))